# BerkeleyLM: Get n-gram probability

Tags: nlp, n-gram

I have a BerkeleyLM language [model](https://berkeleylm.googlecode.com/svn-history/r529/trunk/doc/edu/berkeley/nlp/lm/io/LmReaders.html#readKneserNeyLmFromTextFile%28java.util.List,%20edu.berkeley.nlp.lm.WordIndexer,%20int,%20edu.berkeley.nlp.lm.ConfigOptions,%20boolean%29) and want to use it to get the probability in that model of a given n-gram (which comes from a sentence).

I have tested both methods as listed below but they do not return probabilities but negative numbers, e.g., -1.111 or -5. What is done wrong here?

- [getLogProb](https://berkeleylm.googlecode.com/svn-history/r529/trunk/doc/edu/berkeley/nlp/lm/ArrayEncodedProbBackoffLm.html#getLogProb%28java.util.List%29)
- [scoreSentence](https://berkeleylm.googlecode.com/svn-history/r529/trunk/doc/edu/berkeley/nlp/lm/AbstractArrayEncodedNgramLanguageModel.html#scoreSentence%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 2):

getLogProb 
- You should notice the method name: "Log" of a number less than 1 is negative. 
They return log of the probability instead of probability.

Comment: Well that seems like a good explanation. Do you happen to have any idea what that is? I mean, why would I be interested in the log of p rather than p itself?

Comment: This is because the probability of a long sequence of words is the product of a bunch of probabilities which are all less than 1. This can become very small and cause problems due to floating point limitations. This is why we work in log space. It also makes taking derivatives easier.